# GWT Deployment on Tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, gwt

I'm trying to deploy my GWT project to a remote server. I'm being unable to make it run properly. For some reason the browser looks for the resources relative to the domain root and not relative to the html page location.

The project has the following files structure after deployment:

```
/public_html/ProjectName
/public_html/ProjectName/ProjectName.html
/public_html/ProjectName/WEB-INF
/public_html/ProjectName/META-INF
/public_html/ProjectName/Css
/public_html/ProjectName/Images
/public_html/ProjectName/ProjectName/ProjectName.nocache.js
/public_html/ProjectName/ProjectName/hosted.html
/public_html/ProjectName/ProjectName/etc...
```

As for the images an example how I did it is this found on my uibinder.xml:

```
<g:Image ui:field="imgLogo" styleName="{style.img-logo}" url="/images/logo.png"/>
```

You can see it for yourself on:

http://www.tattoon.pt/webtattoon/

The app is working fine while in development.

I tried to deploy the default GWT to the same server. Unfortunately I get the same error stating that the URL wasn't found when I make the send request. You can check it on:

http://www.tattoon.pt/deployment/

And here is the web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ohapp.deployment.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/deployment/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I know that the project works because I deployed it in another server and achieved the pretended result:

http://metalemore.com:8080/deployment/

Also I already tested the Tomcat server and is working:

http://tattoon.pt/jsptest.jsp

The only difference  is the fact that one server uses Tomcat version 7.0.42 on port 8080 and the one that doesn't work uses Tomcat 5.5.36 on port 80.

I'm using GWT 2.6.0.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: And you deployed it to both servers using the exact same files and procedure? And there's nothing in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: Trying ../images/logo.png instead of /images/logo.png on http://www.tattoon.pt/webtattoon/ works. Can you post the structure of your project ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Yes they are exactly the same project and were deployed the same way. I'm using a shared tomcat instance and I don't have access to the log.

Comment: @Moh I added the file structure to the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to the structure of your project :

- If you're using images in the client side classes, the link should be relative to the `ProjectName.html`, so it should be `images/logo.png` as you did for the CSS (css/Webtattoon.css)
- If you're using images from the `CSS` file, the URL should be `../images/logo.png`

Although, I can't see why it works on Tomcat7 and not on Tomcat 5.5.36.

The browser cache can play tricks on you when it comes to resources's URLs, so make sure that you start a private browsing each time you change a resource or a link.

Answer (score 0):

As per error message received while hitting Send button on this http://www.tattoon.pt/deployment/ URL that says:

The requested URL `/deployment/deployment/greet` was not found on this server.

Its clear that URL is incorrectly formed. There are one extra `/deployment` is found that is causing this issue.

Please confirm what have you specified in your application for below things.

**Note:** Here I have created a remote service with a name as `greet`. May be you have defined it as `deployment/greet` that's why URL is incorrectly formed.

**RemoteService.java:**

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("greet")
public interface GreetService extends RemoteService {
    ...
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.x.y.z.server.GreetServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/deployment/greet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I added the contents of my web.xml file. As you can see is the same as you suggested. Also I must point that it works on a different server so I can't see what is different between the servers that causes this.

Comment: It can create problem if `URL Pattern` are not in same case as defined in `web.xml` and in `RemoteService`.

Comment: First I thank you for your time. I can see a problem there but I think we are missing the point. The exact same deployment worked on a different server. I am confused because in one case it assumed a relative path and the other a fixed. What could I've done wrong? Also the GreetServiceImpl is exactly equal to yours. The code in question wasn't write by me but by google. Is the default project. What else can I do to help pin point the problem?

Comment: I am analyzing this issue and I came to this point that there is some problem in `X-GWT-Module-Base` that is equal to `http://www.tattoon.pt/deployment/deployment/`. Which is wrong. Let me update the  screenshot in my answer.

Comment: `X-GWT-Module-Base` must be equal to `http://www.tattoon.pt/deployment`. I have created a same application same URL but its working fine for me. Is it working fine in Eclipse?

Comment: Yes it's working fine on Eclipse and on another server I have. I don't know how to correct the error. Is there anything wrong with my web.xml configuration? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49850/discussion-between-braj-and-belyid)